# Why doesn't this DC motor run?

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor, 24v

I have a [BG 2212 DC motor.](https://www.ebmpapst.com/content/dam/ebm-papst/media/brochures/products/Brochure_Tangential-blowers-with-multiple-housings_EN.pdf)

It has 6 pin connector. I tried to connect gnd and the + connector to a 20V/24V power supply but the motor did not spin at all.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, you need to ask a question that needs answering. Like "Why it does not run?" or something else you want to know.

Comment: read the `electrical interfaces` section in the second picture ... what does it tell you to do?

Answer (score 0):

It reads in the page you posted, with power supplies provided but no control signal the motor stands sill.

So it works exactly like the manual says.

Comment: Whats should i do to make it spin?

Comment: Give it a control signal according to the specs that makes it spin at the speed you want.

Comment: could you send me what i need to buy to do that? and also how should i connect it ?Thanks:)

Comment: @Camaro46 Asking what to buy and from where is off topic. Can you find the part about the control signal in the documentation you posted? There is a clear description of what kind of signal you need and where you need to connect it.

Comment: no i havent found what controller to get in docs so thats why i asked which one i need to get

Comment: @Camaro46 The documentation says what kinds of control signals it supports. If you want to buy what you call a "controller" then buy one which has any type of output the motor accepts as input. We cannot tell you what to buy.

Comment: @Camaro46 There are several kinds of controllers that do different things, and we don't know what you're ultimately trying to do, so we don't know what kind of controller you need. There are three steps you're going to need to follow. Step 1 is to decide what you want the motor to do—do you just want it to run at a constant speed or do you want to do something more complex? Step 2 is to figure out what type of signal you need to send to the motor in order to get it to do that. Step 3 is to figure out what device you can use in order to produce that kind of signal.

Comment: @Camaro46 You should tackle these steps one at a time; don't worry about step 2 until you're done with step 1, and don't worry about step 3 until you're done with step 2. If all of this sounds complicated, then I recommend following a walkthrough or a course that's related to what you want to do, and then when you come back to this project, it will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet says you need to provide pin 4 with either a 0-10VDC control signal or a 10V PWM signal.  If the pin is left unconnected, the motor will not run.

You can make a 0-10V signal with a potentiometer and I'd probably use an op-amp voltage follower since it doesn't say how much current it takes. The PWM signal can be provided from any square wave source (Arduino, 555, etc). If you just want the motor to run at full speed, then apply 10V to pin 4.

Comment: Based on the schematics control current can be known. It can't be more than 0.1 mA with those values.

Comment: Oh yes true true.

Comment: Hi so i have tried to connect it to computer motherboard with 4 pin header for FAN ,and it worked. Now the question is if i want to use the motor with 24v psu, where do i connect speed output and control voltage? yeah i would like to set RPM manually so it would be quiet in use . Also i have read that its possible to run motor with analog 1-10v imput so how could i run it without quare wave source like the motherboard was